# Confused with fork()

Tags: c, fork

I am having a difficult time understanding what the fork() command does under different scenarios. Here is some sample code from my book:

```
int main() {
    int a = 12;
    int b = 9;
    int fid = fork();

    if (fid == 0) {
        a++;
    }
    else {
        wait(NULL);
        b = b - 5;
    }

    printf("program exit. a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone walk me through what the fork() command is doing in this case and perhaps give some more examples to clarify?

Comment: Note that there is no multi-threading (tag removed) when dealing with `fork()`.  You are dealing with multiple processes (multi-processing) rather than multiple threads within a single process (multi-threading).

Comment: fork() can also return -1, maybe you handle this with a switch(fid) {...} instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
                 [main]
                 a = 12
                 b = 9

                 fork()
                   |
                   |
    +--------------+--------------+
    |                             |  
    |                             |
[parent]                       [child]

fid = 1234                     fid = 0
wait(NULL)                     a++
   ...                         printf("a = 13, b = 9");
   ...                         return 0
   ...                         <exit>
b = b - 5
printf("a = 12, b = 4");
return 0
<exit>
```

After `fork()` executes there are two copies of the program. Each process gets its own copies of the variables, so there are now two `a`'s, two `b`'s, etc. The only difference between the two programs is the value returned from `fork()`: in the child process `fork()` returns 0; in the parent process it returns the PID of the child.

The child process increments `a`, prints the values of `a` and `b`, and exits.

The parent process first waits for the child process to terminate. Only after the child has finished does it continue on, subtracting 5 from `b`, printing out `a` and `b`, and then exiting.

The `wait(NULL)` ensures that the child process's printout always comes before the parent's, so you will always get the same output in a reliable order. Without it you wouldn't be able to depend on the order of the two printouts. They would be the same messages, just in an unpredictable order.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was wondering how to handle questions that ask for output. This makes a lot of sense now. So the correct output for this would be `program exit. a = 13, b = 9` followed by `program exit. a = 12, b = 4`?

Answer (score 4):

1. `a` is set to 12, `b` is set to 9.
2. `fork` is called, we now have two processes.
3. The parent gets the PID of the child, and goes to the `else` clause. The child gets 0, and goes to the `if` clause.
4. The parent waits for the child to finish.
5. The child increments its copy of `a`. So `a` is now 13 in the child and 12 in the parent.
6. The child exits, outputting `13` and `9`.
7. The parent subtracts 5 from its copy of `b`, so `b` is now 4 in the parent.
8. The parent exits, outputting `12` and `4`.

Note that the exact order of execution of the child and parent after `fork` is not guaranteed, but it doesn't change the results because the parent waits for the child to finish before it does anything.

Also, note that having both processes exit normally is bad practice. When one process exits normally, it runs cleanup handlers that can confuse the other process, for example by changing the file position on shared file descriptions, causing data corruption.

Comment: Thanks so much for the step-by-step. In this scenario, after the parent process makes the wait() call, would you say that it will be blocked until the child process finishes (after the child process outputs `13` and `9`?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, exactly. The purpose of the `wait` call is to block the parent until the child completes (or a non-restartable signal interrupts the call).

Comment: Crystal clear explanation. Thanks again! I wish my book had more examples to practice.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `fork()`, the entire process including all memory/variables etc... are duplicated.

So after the `fork` call, each process has it's own copy of `a` and `b` which start as `12` and `9` respectively.

Process 0, will increment it's own copy of `a`. Process 1 will decrement (by 5) it's own copy of `b`.

So they should print:

```
Process 0: a = 13, b = 9
Process 1: a = 12, b = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Its o/p would be
Parent :: a=12 , b=4
Child :: a=13 , b=9

as both process execute simultaneously but both have different copies of local variables a,b
so local var. affected by one process will not be visible to another process as both are working on their own copies